# Spring Integration - Unable to see metrics for MessageHandler, MessageChannel and MessageSource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a prometheus metrics registry and captor beans registered as seen below:

```json
"prometheusMeterRegistry": {
          "aliases": [],
          "scope": "singleton",
          "type": "io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry",
          "resource": "class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]",
          "dependencies": [
              "prometheusConfig",
              "collectorRegistry",
              "micrometerClock"
              ]
 },

"integrationMicrometerMetricsCaptor": {
          "aliases": [],
          "scope": "singleton",
          "type": "org.springframework.integration.support.management.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsCaptor",
          "resource": null,
          "dependencies": []
},
```

However, when I check the `actuator/prometheus` endpoint, I don't see any metrics for `MessageHandler`, `MessageChannel` and `MessageSource` which are mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M1/reference/html/metrics.html#micrometer-integration). The only `spring-integeration` metrics available are:

`spring_integration_sources 1.0`

`spring_integration_handlers 17.0`

`spring_integration_channels 15.0`

I also ran data through my flows, still can't see the metrics. What am I missing?

Comment: Any chances to have a simple Spring Boot project to play with? What is Prometheus? Do I need to install something special?

Comment: Prometheus -> https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus Spring boot -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-export-prometheus. Should I try the same on one of the samples from spring-integration-samples and send you the results?

Comment: Thanks. So, where is the project to play with, please?

Comment: No, it would be better to have a separate simple project to concentrate only on the problem. It may mislead with the sample...

Comment: I will create one and share in sometime, how do I share it?

Comment: GitHub is the best place. So, you create a repo in your user, commit there and share a link for that repo with us here. Then I'll pull that repo locally and build and debug the project.

Comment: https://github.com/nikhilvasaikar/spring-integration-metrics-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for such a great sample!

So, your problem is here:

```
<!-- Enable Spring Integration Metrics -->
<int:management/>
```

First of all you must not do this since Spring Boot auto-configures this for us. (We probably need to improve Spring Boot docs to mention that feature).

Secondly you still can do this but you need to use this option:

```
        <xsd:attribute name="default-counts-enabled" use="optional">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    The default value for components that don't match 'counts-enabled-patterns'.
                    Defaults to false, or true when an Integration MBean Exporter is provided.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

and set it to `true`.

In the current Spring Integration `5.4` version it is deprecated already. We definitely are going to remove it altogether in the next `6.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much, highly appreciate your support !